# Как из метода вернуть несколько значений?

Tags: c#, ооп

Начал осваивать ООП.
Допустим, нужно вернуть координату Х и координату Y, не используя массив. Можно ли это осуществить через double?

Comment: Подождать следующий релиз шарпа)))

Comment: если вы речь ведёте про ООП, то стоит завести класс PointD, в котором будут свойства с нужными координатами. а учитывая особенности c#, то лучше не класс, астуктуру

Comment: Или классы\структуры или Tuple или C#7 или, кхе-кхе, dynamic и анонимные объекты

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void GetXY(out double x, out double y)
{
    x = 20;
    y = 10;
}
```

Используем метод:

```
double x;
double y;

GetXY(out x, out y);
```

Comment: А за что минус? Вполне валидный способ.